# Magento 2 upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4 not working via composer - php is already at version 7.4 before the upgrade!

Tags: magento2, composer, framework

Situation: Magento 2 upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4 not working via composer - php is already at version 7.4 before the upgrade!

These commands executed fine

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=8G composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update`

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=8G composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update`

And we needed to remove 1 package that had php stability as `~7.3`

`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=8G composer remove package/package --no-update`

BUt now we see (shortened here, but repeated vesion numbers like

`tig/postnl-magento2 1.9.4.1 requires magento/framework`

`magento/framework 102.0.5-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.10) does not satisfy that requirement.`

So it would seem we cannot upgrade due to? `magento/framework`? in it's composer file I can see

```
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0",
```

Also I can see `tig/postnl-magento2` has in it's composer file I can see

```
        "php": "~7.0|~7.1|~7.2|~7.3",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "magento/framework": ">=100.1.0,<=100.1.18|>=101.0.0,<=101.0.11|~102.0",
```

**question**: is there a way to work around these 2 limiting dependencies? And also: how come the magento/framework does not want to upgrade if M2.4 is based on php 4.0 ....

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you have to downgrade PHP to 7.3, do the Magento upgrade and then upgrade PHP back to 7.4.